Empty Response in Java Spring Boot Hibernate JPA + PostgreSQL
I am new in Java and trying to create a simple web application for CRUD functions using RestfulAPI.
Employee.java
package project.test.entity;

import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

import java.util.Date;

@Entity
@Data
@Getter
@Setter
@Table(name = "Employee")
public class Employee {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "EmployeeID")
    private String EmployeeID;

    @Column(name = "FirstName")
    private String FirstName;

    @Column(name = "MiddleName")
    private String MiddleName;

    @Column(name = "LastName")
    private String LastName;

    public Employee() {

    }

    public Employee(String EmployeeID, String FirstName, String MiddleName, String LastName) {
        super();
        this.EmployeeID = EmployeeID;
        this.FirstName = FirstName;
        this.MiddleName = MiddleName;
        this.LastName = LastName;
    }

    public String getEmployeeID() {
        return EmployeeID;
    }

    public void setEmployeeID(String EmployeeID) {
        this.EmployeeID = EmployeeID;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return FirstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String FirstName) {
        this.FirstName = FirstName;
    }

    public String getMiddleName() {
        return MiddleName;
    }

    public void setMiddleName(String MiddleName) {
        this.MiddleName = MiddleName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return LastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String LastName) {
        this.LastName = LastName;
    }

}

EmployeeRepository.java
package project.test.repository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import project.test.entity.Employee;

public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, String> {
}

EmployeeService.java
package project.test.service;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import project.test.entity.Employee;
import project.test.repository.EmployeeRepository;

@Service
public class EmployeeService {
    @Autowired
    private EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;

    public List<Employee> getAllEmployees() {
        return employeeRepository.findAll();
    }
}

EmployeeController.java
package project.test.controller;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import project.test.entity.Employee;
import project.test.service.EmployeeService;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class EmployeeController {
    @Autowired
    private EmployeeService employeeService;

    // Get all employees
    @GetMapping("/Employee")
    public List<Employee> getAllEmployees() {
        return employeeService.getAllEmployees();
    }
}

When I load localhost:8080/api/Employee, it shows an empty list even though I already have data in the table Employee in the PostgreSQL database.
Here is my Hibernate SQL execution:
Hibernate: select e1_0.EmployeeID,e1_0.FirstName,e1_0.LastName,e1_0.MiddleName from Employee e1_0

Could anybody please tell me why it does not response the JSON data as expected?

Attach the debugger to your program, put a breakpoint in your controller and see what's happening.

Where do you think a problem is? Hope you understand that it is not in responding JSON output data.

I think the problem might come from the SQL query:
When I run the Hibernate SQL query in PostgreSQL, it returns an empty table (which I assume it creates itself). The SQL query that works in PostgreSQL looks like this: SELECT "EmployeeID", "FirstName", "MiddleName", "LastName" FROM "Employee" The one I tried was: select e1_0.EmployeeID,e1_0.FirstName,e1_0.LastName,e1_0.MiddleName from Employee e1_0 (I don't know if e1_0 is a problem here). I don't know how to make the findAll() generate the right SQL.

And the query database returns an empty results?

SELECT "EmployeeID", "FirstName", "MiddleName", "LastName" FROM "Employee"
This query works and returns the data in PostgreSQL.
select e1_0.EmployeeID,e1_0.FirstName,e1_0.LastName,e1_0.MiddleName from Employee e1_0
This Hibernate query that I took from the terminal does not work and returns an empty table.

Does your database use a case sensitive table names?

No, it doesn't. I figured out the problem is the quotation marks. @Hudson brought up a solution below but I still wonder if there is any solutions using findAll() method.

So, in case you do not want to use findAll(), you can use @Query to directly write a proper query that I can be sure it works in PostgreSQL:
@Query(value = "SELECT \"EmployeeID\", \"FirstName\", \"MiddleName\", \"LastName\" FROM \"Employee\"", nativeQuery = true)
    List<Employee> NqgetAllEmployees();

The tricky part of the repository methods (in PostgreSQL situation specifically) is the quotation marks that can make PostgreSQL misunderstand and instead of overwriting the methods, I think it's easier to write the direct query.
It would be nice if someone could tell what is better, repository methods or native query.

I think you missing @Repository in your repository class .Can you add @Repository in EmployeeRepository and then try again?
@Repository
public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee,String>


I actually tried it and it still did not respond.

Can you make sure that your app is connecting to the right database? Can you provide application.properties file ?

I am sure that it connects to the right database because I tried earlier creating a new table for the database and it actually did the job.
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/HRDatabase
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=postgres

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl

spring.jpa.show-sql=true


Have you tried to execute the Hibernate SQL execution log manually with your Postgres?

Adding @Repository to a Spring Data repository will yield no effect, it will only add code/clutter.

I think @Kezlo spotted the problem. When I run the Hibernate SQL query in PostgreSQL, it returns an empty table (which I assume it creates itself).
The SQL query that works in PostgreSQL looks like this:
SELECT "EmployeeID", "FirstName", "MiddleName", "LastName" FROM "Employee"
The one I tried was:
select e1_0.EmployeeID,e1_0.FirstName,e1_0.LastName,e1_0.MiddleName from Employee e1_0
(I don't know if e1_0 is a problem here).
I don't know how to make the findAll() generate the right SQL.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
